# Hiding Layers on click observer

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have many layers in the Documents that will be displayed on different user interactions. Now I want to hide these Layer if user clicks anywhere else in the Document. These layer have different IDs.

Is there any generic way to register only a single Observer for all such layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a click event listener to the `document.body` node and inspect the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) property to see if it's inside or outside your layers, this should work fine in the bubbling phase if you don't `stopPropagation` of the event anywhere, however you can capture it in the capturing phase by supplying `true` as the last argument to `addEventListener` if that isn't the case. Making this cross-browser compatible is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: But how to check if a layer is visible?

Comment: Well, if you're hiding them with `el.style.display = "none"` then you can just compare `var hidden = (el.style.display == "none");`. Without code I can't really help much further - there's so many different ways of doing it...